# How to enable all site confs with a2ensite (while passing over 000-default.conf && default-ssl.conf)?

Tags: apache2, configuration, automation, virtualhost

I use Ubuntu server 16.04.2 with Apache2, on which I store my personal websites.

To enable all my conf files under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (besides `000-default.conf` and `ssl-default.conf`), I went to `/var/www/html` and executed `a2ensite`.

I was then told:

```
Your choices are: 
000-default default-ssl domain.tld1 domain.tld2 domain.tld3 domain.tld4 
Which site(s) do you want to enable (wildcards ok)?
```

I then did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> aiming to execute something else.

I am looking for a way to automatically enable all site confs, without noting a specific one --- I just want to run a command that will enable all site confs that I myself added.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Might aswell just use find on your config directory.

```
find /etc/apache2/sites-available/ -type f -and -not -name "*default*" -exec a2ensite {} \;
```

This finds all your configuration files that are not having "default" in their name and activates them.

Comment: You should also search for files that have a `*.conf` extension. Or else a2ensite would complain that the site does not exist

Comment: @Dan not necessary since we are searching in the conf directory.

Comment: I guess this method is also good, by principle, when creating Nginx Sblocks, and not only for Apache Vhosts.

Answer (score 14):

You need to navigate to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and then run the command:

```
sudo a2ensite *
```

It will enable all sites in the directory. (the files should be somthing like xxx.conf)

And then reload apache using `sudo service apache2 reload`.

So your command sequence should be like so:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo a2ensite *
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: This also enables the conf file `default-ssl.conf`... This is clear from the output `Enabling site default-ssl.`

Comment: You can use `dpkg -S` to see if the configuration file is from a package.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what our current location is, the command `sudo a2ensite "*.conf"` will attempt to enable all configuration files placed in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.

Next we can use `a2dissite 000-default.conf default-ssl.conf` to disable the default Apache's configurations and then we can use `systemctl restart apache2.service` to restart it.

We can run this all like a single command:

```
sudo bash -c "a2ensite '*.conf' && a2dissite 000-default.conf default-ssl.conf && systemctl restart apache2.service"
```

Something more, we can create a custom command via a function in bash:

```
function a2ensites {
        sudo bash -c "a2ensite '*.conf' && a2dissite 000-default default-ssl && systemctl restart apache2.service"
}
export -f a2ensites
```

Now we have the command `a2ensites`, designed to do this job. To make this command permanent, we must place the above lines into the bottom of `~/.bashrc` file and then `source` it. Next simple script will accomplish this task:

```
 printf "\nfunction a2ensites { \n\tsudo bash -c \"a2ensite '*.conf' && a2dissite 000-default.conf default-ssl.conf && systemctl restart apache2.service\" \n}\nexport -f a2ensites\n" | tee -a $HOME/.bashrc; source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Comment: The first line is not true. The `*` wildcard is being expanded before it gets passed to the `a2ensite` command in my case. However, this works `sudo a2ensite "*.conf"`.

Comment: Hi, @Dan, in my case (Ubuntu 16.04.2) it works properly without quotes. However I've updated the answer. Could you check if `a2ensite '*.conf'` works correct in your system?

Comment: Yep it works, I'm on Ubuntu 17.04 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `a2ensite /var/www/html/*/` will make Apache enable each site conf that has the **same name**, as the site dir.

As a side effect, it will also try to match site dirs that aren't matching for site conf files, as predicted from the following output, but I think this can be ignored safely:

```
ERROR: Site /var/www/html/domain.tld1 does not exist!
ERROR: Site /var/www/html/domain.tld2 does not exist!
ERROR: Site /var/www/html/nice_directory does not exist!
ERROR: Site /var/www/html/nice_file does not exist!
```

You will likely need to restart Apache after enabling conf files:

```
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but why are your site configuration in the webroot folder? Try using the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder for configurations for your sites. Once you enable them via a2ensite, they are automatically linked into `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. What you are doing right now is pretty weird and everyone that has access to your webserver can look into your configurations?

Comment: Hi @Ziazis . I really don't understand, why you even ask me "everyone that has access to your webserver can look into your configurations?" I am the onlyone who uses the server; If I wasn't, than usually other users wouldn't have access to document root. Anyway, can you please clarify why you ask that and what exactly you find wrong?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you are using this webserver for. However if this is a live system with an access which is reachable by a third party you don't want your configuration files lying in `/var/www/html` since that is the DocumentRoot of the `default.html`-Site. So in your case you seem to be running the configurations in there... It's like eating with an open mouth, don't do that ;-).

Comment: I don't understand. You think I putted the conf files in document root? Because I didn't. You suggest me of putting them there? I would want to avoid that... I just want to enable all of them which are not 000-default and default-ssl. BTW, I use the webserver to store my personal websites.

Comment: Ah, I see - you named all your RootDirectories the same same as your config files. And here I thought you changed your apache2 config to have `/var/www/html` as your config folder. Nvm then. What you actually need is just a `find ./ -type f -and -not -name "*default*" -exec a2ensite {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

copy paste the following lines in file name `apache_enable.sh`

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
a2ensite *
service apache2 reload
```

and give read+execute command to `apache_enable.sh` and execute the script using root user

Answer (score 0):

Move the default configs to another folder and then the * should work for you as you want it to.

Go to the folder "sites-available" since it only works in this folder.

> cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
>
> sudo a2ensite *

[image: tested]

Comment: AFAIK, you could do so from anywhere in the system when you document root is /var/www/html?

Comment: The important part is the /etc/apache2_or_other/sites-available folder. The document root is then linked in that config. You could have your root in /usr/share/htlm and it would not change anything except if you did not write it in the conf file. I can be anywhere in my server, as long as the conf files are in the sites-available folder a2ensite will do its work.

Comment: Edited my answer as the first option does not work *tested*