# Search a directory for files and output result to a text file

Tags: command-line

Is there some command to search a directory for files and output the result to a file with a prefix text before name of file that was found?

For example, I have a directory with these files:

```
sound1
sound2
sound3 
…
```

Then give a command to search the directory and write the results to a text file with a prefix before it, e.g.

```
media sound1
media sound2
media sound3
…
```

#### Bonus question

Is there a way to write "media1", "media 2" etc... instead of just "media" to an existing text file without deleting what was inside that text file before?

```
media1 sound1
media2 sound2
media3 sound3
…
```

Comment: Based on what criteria are the files supposed to be found (and possibly classified as media content)?

Answer (score 4):

How about a simple `for` loop?

```
for i in *; do echo media $i >> text_file; done
```

#### Explanations

- `*` – expands to every file in the current directory
- `echo media $i` – prints “media ” and the currently processed filename
- `>> text_file` – redirects the output of `echo` to a file called `text_file` appending it

#### Example

```
$ ls
sound1  sound2  sound3

$ for i in *; do echo media $i >> text_file; done

$ cat text_file 
media sound1
media sound2
media sound3
```

### Bonus question

```
k=0; for i in *; do ((k++)); echo media$k $i >> text_file; done
```

Or for **very** many files (slightly faster):

```
j=text_file; k=0; for i in *; do if [[ "$i" != "$j" ]]; then ((k++)); echo media$k $i; fi; done > "$j"
```

#### Explanations

- `k=0` – define variable `k` and set it to `0`
- `((k++))` – increment `$k` by one

#### Example

```
$ ls
sound1  sound2  sound3

$ k=0; for i in *; do ((k++)); echo media$k $i >> text_file; done

$ cat text_file 
media1 sound1
media2 sound2
media3 sound3
```

Comment: Nice and simple :) You can change it in this way: `for i in *; do echo media${i} $i >> text_file; done` to meet [this requirement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960486/search-a-directory-for-files-and-output-result-to-a-text-file/960491?noredirect=1#comment1534781_960489).

Comment: ls -1v | awk '{printf "media%d %s\n", NR, $0}' > text_file  works perfectly if you make it       ls -1v | awk '{printf "media%d %s\n", NR, $0}' >> text_file   (add a ">" symbol before file name

Comment: @joblade It doesn't work for me, but includes `text_file` in the output – I added my alternative solution.

Comment: Why do you open&close the file on each iteration? You could instead simply do `for .... done > text_file`.

Comment: @Ruslan Did you try this solution? You can't do that because `*` will then also list `text_file`. You could exclude it with `[[ "$i" != text_file ]] && …` though.

Comment: @Ruslan Just tested with 100 files and `time`: The `echo >> text_file` way needs 0.011s, the `done > text_file`way with `if` statement needs 0.007s. I don't consider this a great enough difference in everyday use. Still I'll edit it in – thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 4):

This aught to help:

```
find /path/to/sound/files -type f -name "sound[0-9]" -printf 'media %f\n' > file.txt
```

Information:

`sound[0-9]`: Look for file with names that have `sound` and ends with a number

`-printf 'media %f\n'`: Format the filesname with a prefix of media.

`> file.txt`:  Send it to file called file.txt.

Comment: @Dessert thanks man been trying to get that to work :-)

Comment: The filename expression should be quoted: `-name "sound[0-9]"`, otherwise `find` returns: `find: paths must precede expression: sound2`.

Comment: @pa4080 it works ok on my system

Comment: I have 16.04, where, it throws the above error :)

Comment: Strange things happens at times

Comment: You can replace `-exec bash -c 'echo media ${0##*/} >> file.txt' {} \;` with `-printf 'media %f\n' > file.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver beautiful tried that but couldn't get the `-printf` part working

Comment: @steeldriver updated, concise aand crisp -- just as I like it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi, George, I've investigated this issue with the quote marks. When I run the command within Ubuntu itself, they are not required. But when I run the command via PUTTY's SSH connection (from Windows) the quote marks are required. I remember also this similar issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916377/how-to-enable-all-site-confs-with-a2ensite-while-passing-over-000-default-conf#comment1449768_918583).

Comment: @pa4080 nice, then best to use quotes since it works on both.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` command in this way:

```bsh
find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "media $(basename {}) "' \; > sound.txt
```

Explanation:

- The first argument is the path to the directory, in the example this is the current directory `.`, but you can change it to `/any/desired/path/`.
- `! -name 'sound.txt'` - means that items with name `sound.txt` will be omitted.
- `-type f` - means only files will be finding.
- `-exec <command> \;` - instruct the `find` command to execute `<command>`.
- `{}` is the output argument from the entire command before `-exec` - `find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f`.
- `sh -c 'echo "media $(basename {}) "'` is the `<command>` that will be executed:

  - `sh -c` - execute a command within `/bin/sh` shell;
  - `'echo "media $(basename {}) "'` - command to be executed:
  - `echo "<something>"` - output `<something>` to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams);
  - `media` - just a string;
  - `$(<some command>)` - treat the result of `<some command>` as string;
  - `basename {}` - print only the filename without its path, where `{}` is the variable that contains the full filename generated by `find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f`
- Finally `>` redirects STDOUT;
- `sound.txt` is the name of the file where STDOUT will be redirected.

---

**Update from the comments.** Within the comments there are two suggestions for simplification of the above command:

- The initial command:

  ```bsh
  find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -exec sh -c 'echo "media $(basename {}) "' \;
  ```
- Dessert's suggestion:

  ```bsh
  find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -exec sh -c 'echo media ${0##*/}' {} \;
  ```
- Steeldriver's suggestion:

  ```bsh
  find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -printf 'media %f\n'
  ```

---

**Example of usage.** Let's assume we have a directory with the following structure:

```bsh
$ tree .
.
├── sound
├── sound1
├── sound2
├── sound3
├── sound4
├── sound5
├── sound99
└── soundd
```

The outputs of each of the above command will be identical each other:

```bsh
$ find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -printf 'media %f\n'
media sound1
media soundd
media sound3
media sound5
media sound2
media sound
media sound99
media sound4
```

---

**Bonus question.** According to the *bonus question*, the `find` command isn't the best choice, but its output could be piped (`|`) to another command or cycle. And here are two cases:

- The first case is when we want to just count the *`media#`* results:

  ```bsh
  find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -printf 'media %f\n' | sort | \
  while read -r i; do \
      count=$((count+1)); \
      echo $i | sed "s/media/media$count/"; \
  done
  ```

  The example output of this command will be:

  ```bsh
  $ find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -printf 'media %f\n' | sort | while read -r i; do count=$((count+1)); echo $i | sed "s/media/media$count/"; done
  media1 sound
  media2 sound1
  media3 sound2
  media4 sound3
  media5 sound4
  media6 sound5
  media7 sound99
  media8 soundd
  ```
- The other case is when we want to assign the number of each *`sound#`* file to its *`media`* prefix. And because into the example's circumstances has two files without any number within their names (`sound`, `soundd`), we shall add unique number to them, so the prefix will be *`media/#`*:

  ```bsh
  find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -printf 'media %f\n' | sort | \
  while read -r i; do \
      number=$(echo $i | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'); \
      if [ -z $number ]; then \
          count=$((count+1));
          number="\/$count"; \
      fi; \
      echo $i | sed "s/media/media$number\t/"; \
  done
  ```

  Or we can use this more simple syntax:

  ```bsh
  find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -printf 'media %f\n' | sort  | \
  while read -r i; do \
      number=$(echo $i | grep -Eo '[0-9]+'); \
      [ -z $number ] && count=$((count+1)) && number="\/$count"; \
      echo $i | sed "s/media/media$number\t/"; 
  done
  ```

  The example output of this command will be:

  ```bsh
  $ find . ! -name 'sound.txt' -type f -printf 'media %f\n' | sort | while read -r i; do number=$(echo $i | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,99}'); [ -z $number ] && count=$((count+1)) && number="\/$count"; echo $i | sed "s/media/media$number\t/"; done
  media/1  sound
  media1   sound1
  media2   sound2
  media3   sound3
  media4   sound4
  media5   sound5
  media99  sound99
  media/2  soundd
  ```
- Hints:

  - You can [copy and paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkysC.png) a multi line command directly to the terminal.
  - Don't forget `> sound.text` into the end of the command to push the output into a file.
  - [Wired topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960557/grep-eo-0-91-99-is-much-faster-than-grep-eo-0-91-9999-but).

Comment: @dessert: I think this part `! -name 'sound.txt'` solve this issue. Isn't it?

Comment: You can spare `basename` with `-exec sh -c 'echo media ${0##*/}' {} \;`.

Comment: @dessert, thanks for this advice. I'm trying to figure out how can I add a counter for `media #` within `find` command, any ideas?

Comment: You can replace `-exec sh -c 'echo "media $(basename {}) "' {} \;` with `-printf 'media %f\n'`

Comment: Thank you, @steeldriver, I've tried something similar, but without success... I will elaborate the answer.

Comment: @pa4080 I'd just pipe it through this: `sed = | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s/^/media/'`, like `find . ! -name text_file -type f -printf "%f\n" | sed = | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s/^/media/'`

Answer (score 2):

First print the list of files (one entry per line) in a file (`list_of_files`)

```
ls -1 /location/of/the/directory > list_of_files
```

Then add a fixed *prefix* (`media`) to each line

```
sed -i 's/^/media /' list_of_files
```

### Update for bonus question

To add numbering, first print the list of files in a file (say `list_of_files`) as before. Then add line numbers before each line

```
sed -i '=' list_of_files
```

The output would look like this

```
1
sound1
2
sound2
...
```

Then fix the line-breaks

```
sed -i '{N;s/\n/ /}' list_of_files
```

The output would now look like this

```
1 sound1
2 sound2
...
```

Then finally add a fixed *prefix* (`media`) to each line like before

```
sed -i 's/^/media/' list_of_files
```

Final output would be

```
media1 sound1
media2 sound2
...
```

Comment: @dessert `ls` lists one entry per line for me. But better be safe, I changed it as per your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @dessert *Clarification:* What I meant was `ls > filename` prints one entry per line in `filename`, but `ls` in terminal lists names in a single line. I think we were having a little communication gap.

Comment: @dessert it's a feature of many utilities to pretty-print to a tty, but output in a compatible mode when redirected to file. E.g. `ls --color=auto`, `grep --color`, modern `gcc` (≥5.0) by default print colored output to a terminal, but resort to plain text if stdout is not a tty. Similarly, `ls` by default prints multicolumn to a tty, but single-column to not-a-tty. See [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
dir=`find /home/username/ -name script_test`
ls $dir  > test.txt
sed -i -e 's/^/media /' test.txt
```

Comment: Cool stuff. It's working. Is there a way to write "media1", "media 2" etc... instead of just "media" to an existing text file without deleting what was inside that text file before?

Comment: thats very easy i will update. now I'm travelling once reached i will updATe it.

Comment: Even though this solution does work, I'd recommend editing your answer to include an explanation of the commands. That would make it more informative and a better answer overall.

Comment: if you want points take it