# How to remove particular words from lines of a text file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

my text file looks like this:

```
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000205348
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000265725
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000322823
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000376445
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000425341
```

now I want to delete `Liquid penetration 95% mass (m)` from my lines to obtain the values only. How should I do it?

Comment: simply `grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+$' file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: To the moment, this solution gets the ['putty medal'](https://askubuntu.com/a/968178/566421) :)

Comment: @pa4080 At least for the input I tested (10M lines), Avinash Raj's [general approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/968771) can be made an order of magnitude faster by using PCRE. (I could confirm that the engine, not the pattern, is responsible, as GNU grep accepts `\S+$` with either `-E` or `-P`.) So this kind of solution isn't inherently slow. But I still can't get it anywhere close to [αғsнιη's `cut` method](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035), which [won your benchmark](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967980/how-to-remove-particular-words-from-lines-of-a-text-file/968771#comment1550362_968178) too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If there's only one `=` sign, you could delete everything before and including `=` like this:

```
$ sed -r 's/.* = (.*)/\1/' file
0.000205348
0.000265725
0.000322823
0.000376445
0.000425341
```

If you want to change the original file, use the `-i` option after testing:

```
sed -ri 's/.* = (.*)/\1/' file
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE so we don't have to escape `(` and `)`
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `(things)` save `things` to backreference later with `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Comment: Thanks it worked. 
I used this command to overwrite the existing file:
sed -i -r 's/.*= (.*)/\1/' time.txt 

May you explain how does it work?

Comment: Why not avoid the backreference? `s/^.*= //` would work equally well, since the correct value is at the end of the line.

Comment: @jpaugh Well partly because it's too late to change my answer which was the first one posted - others have already given the solution you mention and other more efficient ways for this case :) But maybe showing how to use `\1` etc has some value for people who land on this question when searching, who don't have such a simple problem

Comment: @Zanna It is more general, at least.

Answer (score 21):

This is a job for `awk`; assuming the values occur in last field only (as per your example):

```
awk '{print $NF}' file.txt
```

- `NF` is an `awk` variable, expands to the number of fields in a record (line), hence `$NF` (note the `$` in front) contains the value of the last field.

**Example:**

```
% cat temp.txt 
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000205348
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000265725
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000322823
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000376445
Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000425341

% awk '{print $NF}' temp.txt
0.000205348
0.000265725
0.000322823
0.000376445
0.000425341
```

Answer (score 16):

I decided to compare the different solutions, listed here. For this purpose I've created a large file, based on the content provided by the OP:

1. I created a simple file, named `input.file`:

   ```
   $ cat input.file
   Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000205348
   Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000265725
   Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000322823
   Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000376445
   Liquid penetration 95% mass (m) = 0.000425341
   ```
2. Then I executed this loop:

   ```
   for i in {1..100}; do cat input.file | tee -a input.file; done
   ```
3. Terminal window was blocked. I executed `killall tee` from another terminal. Then I examined the content of the file by the commands: `less input.file` and `cat input.file`. It looked good, except the last line. So I removed the last line and created a backup copy: `cp input.file{,.copy}` (because of the commands that use *inplace* option).
4. The final count of the lines into the file `input.file` is **2 192 473**. I got that number by the command `wc`:

   ```
   $ cat input.file | wc -l
   2192473
   ```

---

Here is the result of the comparison:

- [**`grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+$'`**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967980/how-to-remove-particular-words-from-lines-of-a-text-file/968436#comment1550672_967980)

  ```
  $ time grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+$' input.file > output.file

  real    0m58.539s
  user    0m58.416s
  sys     0m0.108s
  ```
- [**`sed -ri 's/.* = (.*)/\1/'`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/967982/566421)

  ```
  $ time sed -ri 's/.* = (.*)/\1/' input.file

  real    0m26.936s
  user    0m22.836s
  sys     0m4.092s
  ```

  Alternatively if we redirect the output to a new file the command is more faster:

  ```
  $ time sed -r 's/.* = (.*)/\1/' input.file > output.file

  real    0m19.734s
  user    0m19.672s
  sys     0m0.056s
  ```
- [**`gawk '{gsub(".*= ", "");print}'`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968436/566421)

  ```
  $ time gawk '{gsub(".*= ", "");print}' input.file > output.file

  real    0m5.644s
  user    0m5.568s
  sys     0m0.072s
  ```
- [**`rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968137/566421)

  ```
  $ time rev input.file | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev  > output.file

  real    0m3.703s
  user    0m2.108s
  sys     0m4.916s
  ```
- [**`grep -oP '.*= \K.*'`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035/566421)

  ```
  $ time grep -oP '.*= \K.*' input.file > output.file

  real    0m3.328s
  user    0m3.252s
  sys     0m0.072s
  ```
- [**`sed 's/.*= //'`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968436/566421) *(respectively the `-i` option makes the command few times slower)*

  ```
  $ time sed 's/.*= //' input.file > output.file

  real    0m3.310s
  user    0m3.212s
  sys     0m0.092s
  ```
- [**`perl -pe 's/.*= //'`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968436/566421) *(the `-i` option doesn't produce big difference in the productivity here)*

  ```
  $ time perl -i.bak -pe 's/.*= //' input.file

  real    0m3.187s
  user    0m3.128s
  sys     0m0.056s
  ```

  ```
  $ time perl -pe 's/.*= //' input.file > output.file

  real    0m3.138s
  user    0m3.036s
  sys     0m0.100s
  ```
- [**`awk '{print $NF}'`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968025/566421)

  ```
  $ time awk '{print $NF}' input.file  > output.file

  real    0m1.251s
  user    0m1.164s
  sys     0m0.084s
  ```
- [**`cut -c 35-`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968102/566421)

  ```
  $ time cut -c 35- input.file  > output.file

  real    0m0.352s
  user    0m0.284s
  sys     0m0.064s
  ```
- [**`cut -d= -f2`**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035/566421)

  ```
  $ time cut -d= -f2 input.file  > output.file

  real    0m0.328s
  user    0m0.260s
  sys     0m0.064s
  ```

[*The source of the idea.*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960557/grep-e-sed-e-low-performance-when-x1-9999-is-used-but-why)

Comment: so [my `cut -d= -f2` solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035/283843) wins. haha

Comment: Can you give more information about how you created this file? Also, how does `wc -l` output three numbers? When no other options are passed, the `-l` option should suppress everything but the line count.

Comment: @EliahKagan, done. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see -- the spaces were digit group separators. (Had `wc` actually displayed those spaces? Are there locale settings for which it will do that?) Thanks for the update!

Comment: @EliahKagan: Finally I read your questions about `wc` one more time. I do not know where my wits was early today, but I really couldn't understand them. So indeed *the spaces were digit group separators*, and `wc` doesn't add them :)

Answer (score 12):

With [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/grep.1.html) and the `-P` for having [`PCRE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) (Interpret  the pattern as a **P**erl-**C**ompatible **R**egular **E**xpression) and the `-o` to print matched pattern alone. The `\K` notify will ignore the matched part come before itself.

```bsh
$ grep -oP '.*= \K.*' infile
0.000205348
0.000265725
0.000322823
0.000376445
0.000425341
```

Or you could use [`cut`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cut.1posix.html) command instead.

```
cut -d= -f2 infile
```

Comment: In addition to running the fastest of all methods tested in [pa4080's benchmark](https://askubuntu.com/a/968178/22949), **the `cut` method in this answer** was also the clear winner in [a smaller benchmark I ran](https://askubuntu.com/a/968771/22949) that tested fewer methods but used a larger input file. It was well over ten times faster than the fast variant of the method I personally like (and that my answer is mainly about).

Answer (score 11):

Since the line prefix always has the same length (34 characters) you can use `cut`:

```
cut -c 35- < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Reverse the content of the file with `rev`, pipe the output into `cut` with space as delimiter and 1 as the target field, then reverse it again to get the original number:

```
$ rev your_file | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
0.000205348
0.000265725
0.000322823
0.000376445
0.000425341
```

Answer (score 5):

This is simple, short, and easy to write, understand, and check, and I personally like it:

```bash
grep -oE '\S+$' file
```

[`grep` in Ubuntu](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/), when invoked with `-E` or `-P`, takes the [shorthand](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` to mean a [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (in practice *usually* a space or tab) and `\S` to mean anything that isn't one. Using [the quantifier `+`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and [the end-of-line anchor `$`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), **the pattern `\S+$` matches one or more non-blanks at the end of a line**. You can use `-P` instead of `-E`; the meaning *in this case* is the same but [a different regular expressions engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) is used, so they [may have different performance characteristics](https://askubuntu.com/a/960644/22949).

This is equivalent to [Avinash Raj's commented solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967980/how-to-remove-particular-words-from-lines-of-a-text-file#comment1550672_967980) (just with an easier, more compact syntax):

```bash
grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+$' file
```

These approaches won't work if there could be trailing whitespace *after* the number. They can be modified so they do, but I see no point in going into that here. Although it's sometimes instructive to generalize a solution to work under more cases, it's not practical to do so nearly as often as people tend to assume, because one usually has no way to know *in which of many different incompatible ways* the problem might ultimately need to be generalized.

---

Performance is sometimes an important consideration. This question doesn't stipulate that the input is very large, and it's likely that every method that has been posted here is fast enough. However, in case speed is desired, here's a small benchmark on a ten million line input file:

```bash
$ perl -e 'print((<>) x 2000000)' file > bigfile
$ du -sh bigfile
439M    bigfile
$ wc -l bigfile
10000000 bigfile
$ TIMEFORMAT=%R
$ time grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+$' bigfile > bigfile.out
819.565
$ time grep -oE '\S+$' bigfile > bigfile.out
816.910
$ time grep -oP '\S+$' bigfile > bigfile.out
67.465
$ time cut -d= -f2 bigfile > bigfile.out
3.902
$ time grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+$' bigfile > bigfile.out
815.183
$ time grep -oE '\S+$' bigfile > bigfile.out
824.546
$ time grep -oP '\S+$' bigfile > bigfile.out
68.692
$ time cut -d= -f2 bigfile > bigfile.out
4.135
```

I ran it twice in case the order mattered (as it sometimes does for I/O-heavy tasks) and because I didn't have a machine available that wasn't doing other stuff in the background that could skew the results. From those results I conclude the following, at least provisionally and for input files of the size I used:

- Wow! Passing `-P` (to use [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)) rather than `-G` (the default when no dialect is specified) or `-E` made `grep` faster by over an order of magnitude. So for large files, it may be better to use this command than the one shown above:

  ```bash
  grep -oP '\S+$' file
  ```
- **WOW!!** The `cut` method in [**αғsнιη's answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035/22949), `cut -d= -f2 file`, is over an order of magnitude quicker than even the faster version of my way! It was the winner in [pa4080's benchmark](https://askubuntu.com/a/968178/22949) as well, which covered more methods than this but with smaller input--and which is why I chose it, of all the other methods, to include in my test. If performance is important or files are huge, I think [αғsнιη's `cut` method](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035/22949) should be used.

  This also serves as a reminder that **the simple [`cut`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/cut.1.html) and [`paste`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/paste.1.html) utilities [shouldn't be forgotten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well)**, and should perhaps be preferred when applicable, even though there are more sophisticated tools like [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html) that are often offered as first-line solutions (and that I am personally more accustomed to using).

Answer (score 4):

**`perl`** - **s**ubstitute the pattern `/.*= /` with empty string `//`:

```
perl -pe 's/.*= //' input.file > output.file
```

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/.*= //' input.file
```

- From `perl --help`:

  ```
  -e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
  -p                assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
  -i[extension]     edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
  ```

---

**`sed`** - substitute the pattern with empty string:

```
sed 's/.*= //' input.file > output.file
```

or *(but slower than the above)*:

```
sed -i.bak 's/.*= //' input.file
```

- I mention this approach, because it is few times faster than those in Zanna's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967982/566421).

---

**`gawk`** - substitute the pattern `".*= "` with empty string `""`:

```
gawk '{gsub(".*= ", "");print}' input.file > output.file
```

- From `man gawk`:

  ```
  gsub(r, s [, t]) For each substring matching the regular expression r in the string t,
                   substitute the string s, and return the number of substitutions. 
                   If t is not supplied, use $0...
  ```