# How to grep text which is always changing from a line with particular text?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

```
contentJSON is :-
{"id":"0","name":"inc_timestamp","workspaceId":"37158928","infoJSON":"{a:{\"a\":\"bcd\",\"b\":{\"c\":\"d\"}}}","contentJSON":"{\n  \"tasks\": [\n    {\n      \"name\": \"Input\",\n      \"taskType\": \"executeCustomSQLQueryForIncrementalLoad\",\n      \"id\": 10,\n      \"x\": 95,\n      \"y\": 44,\n      \"inputConnectors\": [],\n      \"outputConnectors\": [\n        {\n          \"nodeID\": 11,\n          \"type\": \"Output\",\n          \"name\": \"\"\n        }\n      ],\n      \"argsMap\": {\n        \"taskId\": 10,\n        \"datasetId\": 49053696,\n        \"deltaColumnName\": \"timestamp\",\n        \"deltaColumnDataType\": \"timestamp\",\n        \"deltaColumnValue\": \"null\",\n        \"primaryKeysList\": [\n          \"id\"\n        ]\n      },\n      \"datasetId\": 49053696\n    },\n    {\n      \"name\": \"Output\",\n      \"taskType\": \"saveToES\",\n      \"id\": 11,\n      \"x\": 453,\n      \"y\": 44,\n      \"inputConnectors\": [\n        {\n          \"nodeID\": 10,\n          \"type\": \"Input\",\n          \"name\": \"\"\n        }\n      ],\n      \"outputConnectors\": [],\n      \"argsMap\": {\n        \"bizvizcubeId\": 46759937,\n        \"cfg\": {\n          \"es.mapping.id\": \"id\"\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  ],\n  \"connections\": [\n    {\n      \"source\": {\n        \"taskId\": 10,\n        \"connectorIndex\": 0\n      },\n      \"dest\": {\n        \"taskId\": 11,\n        \"connectorIndex\": 0\n      }\n    }\n  ],\n  \"isIncrementalLoadModeWorkflow\": 1\n}\n"}
Status:200
{"wokspaceResp":{"success":true,"workspaces":[],"params":"{\"id\":\"49086475\"}"}}
{"wokspaceResp":{"success":true,"workspaces":[],"params":"{\"id\":\"49086475\"}"}}
{"success":true,"workspaces":[],"params":"{\"id\":\"49086475\"}"}
{"id":"49086475"}
wfid is : 49086475
finally wfid is : 49086475
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.136s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 24 15:30:48 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/392M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I required to grep `49086475` which changes every time I execute my program.

Please guide me to capture the text after `finally wfid is :`.

Comment: The description of the "grep" family of commands is: print lines matching a pattern; therefore the verb "to grep" must mean something like copy to the output one or more lines from the file. So what is wrong with just `fgrep 'finally wfid is :'`?

Comment: Two suggestions. One - use appropriate tools for the job - if it's `json` use something that understands `json`; and second - when you provide input examples, provide something that is complete, because your input looks like mess and incomplete.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: It looks like only the first entry in the file is JSON.

Answer (score 8):

Use awk:

```
awk '/finally wfid is :/{print $NF}'
```

... which prints the last field of the line containing `finally wfid is :`.

Comment: A minor clarification, use: `awk '/finally wfid is :/{print $NF}' <filename>` or `cat <filename> | awk '/finally wfid is :/{print $NF}'`.

Answer (score 7):

Use `grep` in this way:

```
grep -oP 'finally wfid is : \K.*' <filename>
```

- The explanation from the [source answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035/566421):

  > With [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/grep.1.html) and the `-P` for having [`PCRE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) (Interpret  the
  >   pattern as a **P**erl-**C**ompatible **R**egular **E**xpression) and
  >   the `-o` to print matched pattern alone. The `\K` notify will ignore
  >   the matched part come before itself.

---

Or you can use `sed` in this way:

```
sed -n 's/finally wfid is : //p' <filename>
```

- This command will print only the lines that contain the string `finally wfid is :`, but it will be substituted with empty string.

Answer (score 4):

Despite all the good solutions posted already, I'll add one that only uses `grep`. I often end up doing things this way because of my inability to remember `sed` and `awk` commands.

```
grep 'finally wfid is' input_file | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

The first grep will take the correct line. The second one uses the `-o` argument to take **o**nly matching part of the line, which here is anything numerical.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
grep "finally wfid is" <filename> | awk '{print $5;}'
```

This will output the number which is in that line alone. If you want the whole line just omit the `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that all the answers posted so far
have missed the point of the question. 
Or, perhaps, I have. 
I understand the question to mean

> I need to find the text (eight-digit number)
>   that appears after `finally wfid is :`
>   and then `grep` the file for that text.

The posted answers do the first part fine, but don’t finish the job. 
IMHO, [muru’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/968482/325633#968485) is the best; I’ll build on that:

```
grep "$(awk '/finally wfid is :/{print $NF}' contentJSON)" contentJSON
```

where `$(command)`
captures the output from *`command`* (in this case, the `awk`)
and uses it in the outer command (in this case, `grep`). 
I assume from the question that the filename is `contentJSON`.