# Cutting certain string from a longer string

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have strings:

```
fvvDataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-21oM]
fbbDataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-22oM]
```

I want to strip everything that starts with Data and ends in what looks like a date:

```
DataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-21
DataFolders/DDC/DDB2018-02-22
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you simply want to strip the first three and last three characters? Or everyhing that starts with `Data` and ends in what looks like a date? Or just the characters 4-32? That would be `cut -c 4-32`.

Comment: Would also be nice to know if these are in a file or variable

Comment: @ Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy, they are in a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

```
grep -P -o 'Data.+?\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d'
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/^.+(Data.+?\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d).+$/$1/'
```

will do. They both print the minimal string that starts with `Data` and ends in what looks like a date (YYYY-MM-DD).

```
echo "fvvDataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-21oM]" > input.txt
echo "fbbDataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-22oM]" >> input.txt
grep -P -o 'Data.+?\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d' input.txt

# output:
DataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-21
DataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-22

perl -pe 's/^.+(Data.+?\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d).+$/$1/' input.txt

# output:
DataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-21
DataFolders/DDB/DDB2018-02-22
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command `grep` in this way:

```bsh
grep -oP 'Data.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' input-file > output-file
```

- `-o`, `--only-matching` - show only the part of a line matching PATTERN.
- `-P`, `--perl-regexp` - PATTERN is a Perl regular expression; or in this case could be used also the option `-E`, `--extended-regexp` - PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE).
- the regexp `'Data.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'` matches to your requirements. It begin with the string `Data`, followed by unknown number `*` of any characters `.`, and ends with the date format: `4 digits from 0 to 9` dash `2 digits from 0 to 9` dash `2 digits from 0 to 9`.

Here is also a `sed` solution:

```bsh
sed -r 's/^.*(Data.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*$/\1/' /tmp/input-file
```

- redirect the output to a new file `> output-file` or use the option `-i.bak` to make the changes in their places and create a backup file.
- `-r`, `--regexp-extended` - use extended regular expressions in the script.
- the command `s` means substitute: `/<string-or-regexp>/<replacement>/`.
- `^.*` will match to the beginning `^` of the line, followed by unknown number of any characters.
- `.*$` will match to the end `$` of the line, precede by unknown number of any characters.
- within the the , the capture group `(...)`, will be treated as the variable \1. So the whole line `^.*$` will be substituted by the part that matces to what is in the brackets.

Comment: LOL. Two guys, one thought.

Comment: @PerlDuck, I was inspired by your `perl` example and added also a `sed` solution.

Comment: Nice. I also tried `sed` but as I'm not particular familiar with it I didn't get it working. The `-r` switch is crucial and without it my attempts all failed. /// If I were the asker I'd accept _your_ answer because it also _explains_ things. Plus: you answered 17 seconds quicker. :-)

Comment: @PerlDuck, I really like topics as these, in which a simple question receives large number of answers with different possible solutions. Here is my favourite: [How to remove particular words from lines of a text file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/967980/566421)