# Using time -v to calculate execution time. Command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, time

I'm trying to measure the execution time of a C program I wrote. However, I want to see a detailed output of different times, percent of CPU use, etc. I try

```
time -v ./a.out
```

But I get an error that states the command `-v` was not found. However, I have checked the man pages for `time` and `-v or --verbose` is an option.

What's wrong?

Comment: Maybe the command `valgrind` also could be interesting for you. Here is example of usage: https://askubuntu.com/a/960644/566421

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That means the `time` that you are using is the bash shell built in `time` which the only option is `-p` and you cannot even use `-V`, instead use the actual command with specifying its full path:

```
/usr/bin/time -v ./a.out
```

the man page is for the above command that if you do `which time`, will see `/usr/bin/time`. For the bash built-in `time`, you can `help time`.

Further reading:

- [Where can I find the location of folders for installed programs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54395/566421)
- [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/566421)

Comment: I had to `apt install time` first (in Docker)