# What is the correct way to format this grep?

Tags: command-line, grep, regex

I am having trouble figuring out where to place the `\` in this command.

```
grep "^D.*\(A1|A2|A3\)$" input.txt > output.txt
```

I'm searching for each line that starts with a `D` and ends with A1, A2, or A3, which is at the end of the line.

Comment: Try the `-E` option.

Comment: For this particular case, you could use a simple character range `^D.*A[1-3]$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just needed to escape the or bars - you were almost there:

```
grep "^D.*\(A1\|A2\|A3\)$"
```

Note you can also use egrep instead of all the escapes:

```
egrep "^D.*(A1|A2|A3)$"
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the pipes (`|`).

```
$ grep "^D.*\(A1\|A2\|A3\)$" <(printf 'D%s\n' A1 A2 A3)
DA1
DA2
DA3
```

Or use option `-E` for extended regex, then you don't need to escape anything.

```
$ grep -E "^D.*(A1|A2|A3)$" <(printf 'D%s\n' A1 A2 A3)
DA1
DA2
DA3
```

Comment: We can use also `-P` instead of `-E` and this is really useful in some cases, see: [Grep -E, Sed -E - low performance, but why?](https://askubuntu.com/q/960557/566421)

Answer (score 0):

Here is `sed` implementation, that uses the combination of the option `-n` and the command `p`:

```bsh
sed -rn '/^D.*(A1|A2|A3)$/p' in-file
```

```bsh
sed -n '/^D.*\(A1\|A2\|A3\)$/p' in-file
```

```bsh
sed -n '/^D.*A[1-3]$/p' in-file
```

- option `-r`, `--regexp-extended`: use extended regular expressions in the script.
- option `-n`, `--quiet`, `--silent`: suppress automatic printing of pattern space.
- command `p`: print the current pattern space.