# Find and delete a line that starts with a certain string in a file

Tags: bash, text-processing

My file currently has

```
Name.      Address.   Phone number 
Jack.        L.A             1435672
John         L.A.            1465432
Nick.        F.l.            1489756
```

When the user wants to delete a contact from the list he enters the name of the contact and the program deletes the whole line. When the user wants to modify a contact he enters the name and find the contact and then change it with a new name, address and phone number. I am trying to achieve this using two functions delete and modify.

Comment: Show us some samples of how it is and how it should be!

Comment: That’s fine, but what is your question?

Comment: For example the file has a line.                      Jack       L.A.          1456233.                           So when the user enters Jack the code should delete the whole line

Comment: And another function to modify the name address and phone number

Comment: I think this is done easily with a spreadsheet program, for example Libreoffice Calc (unless the database is too huge). For the sake of learning you can make a bash shellscript with or without using `awk` or `sed`. Anyway, please edit your original question to show us a few lines of the data file with names, addresses and phone numbers and your current version of 'bash code', the shellscript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command `sed` with syntax like as:

```
sed "/^\t$name/d" in-file
```

Where:

- we must use double quotes when inside the regular expression need to pass a shell variable - `$name` in this case.
- `^` will match to the beginning of the line.
- `\t` will match to a single tab.
- the command `d` at the end will delete each line that match to our regexp `/^\t$name/`.

You can add `-i` (or `-i.bak`) to create the changes in place of the file (or and create a backup copy). Or you can Blueirect the output of the command to anotger file, etc.:

```
sed "/^\t$name/d" in-file -i.bak
```

```bsh
sed "/^\t$name/d" in-file > out-file
```

More examples:

```bsh
$ name='Blue'                       # assign a value to the shell variable $name

$ cat in-file                       # output the content of the input file
first line
second line
    Blue
    fourth line
Blue

$ sed "/^\t*$name/d" in-file        # remove the lines that begin ^ with 0 or more tabs followed by the value of $name
first line
second line
    fourth line

$ sed -r "/^\t+$name/d" in-file     # remove the lines that begin ^ with 1 or more tabs followed by the value of $name; enable extended regexp -r
first line
second line
    fourth line
Blue

$ sed -r "/^\t{0,1}$name/d" in-file # remove the lines that begin ^ with 0 or 1 tabs followed by the value of $name; enable extended regexp -r
first line
second line
    fourth line

$ sed -r "/^\t?$name/d" in-file     # remove the lines that begin ^ with 0 or 1 tabs followed by the value of $name; enable extended regexp -r
first line
second line
    fourth line

$ sed -r -e "/^(\t|\s|\s\t|\t\s)?$name/d" -e 's/^\t//' in-file # remove the lines that begin ^ with 0 or 1 tabs, or spaces, or spaces and tabs, or tabs and spaces`; remove the tabs in the beginning of the rest lines 
first line
second line
fourth line
```

---

**Edit:** Here is how to substitute a whole line from the example provided in the updated question. Here is used the `sed`'s substitution command `s/regexp/replacement/`.

First let's assume we have defined the following sets variables:

```bsh
old_name='Jack.' old_address='L.A.' old_phone='1435672'
new_name='Tom.' new_address='F.l.' new_phone='875632'
```

If we need exact match of the line and want to keep the exact format, we can use the following command, that uses capture groups option: `(...)` -> `\1`, etc.; additionally the option `-r` (use extended regular expressions) is applied to simply the syntax (check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1112944/566421) as reference):

```bsh
sed -r "s/^(\t*|\s*)$old_name(\t*|\s*)$old_address(\t*|\s*)$old_phone(\t*|\s*)$/\1$new_name\2$new_address\3$new_phone\4/" in-file
```

In this way we capturing the field separators (that in this case cold tabs and/or spaces) and output them in their place within the replacement string.

If we do not need to be so accurate we can use something more simple as the follow (where in the place of the capture groups our regex will expect 0 or more `*` characters of any type `.`):

```bsh
sed -r "s/^.*$old_name.*$old_address.*$old_phone.*$/$new_name\t$new_address\t$new_phone/" in-file
```

Or even more simple:

```bsh
sed -r "s/^.*$old_name.*$/$new_name\t$new_address\t$new_phone/" in-file
```

Example:

```bsh
$ cat in-file 
Name.   Address.  Phone number
Jack.   L.A.      1435672               
John.   L.A.      1465432
Nick.   F.l.      1489756

$ old_name='Jack.' old_address='L.A.' old_phone='1435672' new_name='Tom.' new_address='F.l.' new_phone='875632'

$ sed -r "s/^(\t*|\s*)$old_name(\t*|\s*)$old_address(\t*|\s*)$old_phone(\t*|\s*)$/\1$new_name\2$new_address\3$new_phone\4/" in-file 
Name.   Address.  Phone number
Tom.    F.l.      875632               
John.   L.A.      1465432
Nick.   F.l.      1489756
```

Comment: Is there any way I can replace the whole line with other user inputs for example in place of jack- tom, l.a - f.l and 1435267- 875632.   Assuming that tom, l.a and 875632 are stored in $newname,$newaddress and$newphone respectively

Comment: @A6du2, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I can’t accept the oldaddress and oldphone from the user so is there any way I can read those from a file given the old name

Comment: @A6du2, yes, you can in several ways, for example you can use the bash builtin `read` in a way like this: `read -r old_name_captured old_address old_phone < <(sed -n "/^.*$old_name.*$/p" in-file)`, where the first `<` feeds the std-in of the `read` command with the content of the "pseudo file" `<(...)`. The default value of `IFS=` is tabs and spaces so `read` will assign the three monolithic strings to the tree newly created variables `old_name_captured`, `old_address` and `old_phone`. Here is a clue abut this usage of `sed`: https://askubuntu.com/a/1113064/566421

Comment: This works but it brings unexpected results in a file for example when i modify john with name john address tx and number 18638438 the it adds johntx18638438 after tom and nicks phone number