# How to use split file into two based on line start?

Tags: command-line, regex, split

I have this file `1.txt`:

```
-e a
b
-e c

d
-e e
f
```

I want to split it into the following two files.

`2.txt`

```
-e a
-e c
-e e
```

`3.txt`

```
b
d
f
```

where `2.txt` contains all the lines starting with `-e`, and `3.txt` contains all the other lines. Extra newlines (such as the extra newline in the middle of the original) can be ignored or kept, and order doesn't matter.

I've tried using `split`, but it doesn't look like that allows me to use a pattern for splitting (instead a fixed number of lines per split file).

Comment: `split` is the wrong tool. Use `grep`. Read ` man grep` and the `man ` pages it refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -E '^-e' 1.txt >2.txt
grep -E '[^-]' 1.txt >3.txt
```

@braemar: Using `grep -v` with the same regexp would erroneously detect blank lines, text lines, etc. Not what was wanted.

Comment: The second command should be `grep -Eo '[^-]' 1.txt`. In addition `-Po` is about 3 times [faster](https://askubuntu.com/q/960557/566421) in this case. Here it is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bVBV4CNFxM/

Comment: Rather than two different regexp, the solution would be more obvious if the second command used `-v` with the same regexp.

Answer (score 3):

Here is `awk` solution:

```
awk '{ if ( /^-/ ) print > "2.txt"; else if ( NF ) print > "3.txt" }' 1.txt
```

---

A performance test:

```
$ cat 1.txt | wc -l | sed -r -e 's/([0-9]{6}$)/ \1/' -e 's/([0-9]{3}$)/ \1 lines/'
1 144 270 lines
$ TIMEFORMAT=%R

$ time awk '{ if ( /^-/ ) print > "2.txt"; else if ( NF ) print > "3.txt" }' 1.txt
0.372
```

Answer (score 2):

Preserving empty lines:

```
$ sed -n -e '/^-e/{w 2.txt' -e 'd}' -e 'w 3.txt' 1.txt
```

giving

```
$ head {1,2,3}.txt
==> 1.txt <==
-e a
b
-e c

d
-e e
f

==> 2.txt <==
-e a
-e c
-e e

==> 3.txt <==
b

d
f
```

If you prefer to omit empty lines, then add an "any character" regex to the last write:

```
sed -n -e '/^-e/{w 2.txt' -e 'd}' -e '/./w 3.txt' 1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `sed` solution by using of `d`elete flag:

```bsh
sed -e '/^-/!d' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

The above command has two regex, the first `'/^-/!d'` will match to all lines that doesn't start with `-` and they will be deleted from the output, the second `'/^[[:space:]]*$/d'` will match to all lines that contains only white spaces and they will be deleted from the output.

```bsh
sed -e '/^-/d' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' 1.txt > 3.txt
```

The above command also has two regex, the first `'/^-/d'` will match to all lines that starts with `-` and they will be deleted from the output, the second is the same as in the previews case.

---

Another way is to preserve `-n` the normal output of `sed` and then `p`rint only the matched lines:

```bsh
sed -n '/^-/p' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

```bsh
sed -n -r '/^(-|[[:space:]]*$)/!p' 1.txt > 3.txt
```

---

Here is a performance test:

```
$ cat 1.txt | wc -l | sed -r -e 's/([0-9]{6}$)/ \1/' -e 's/([0-9]{3}$)/ \1 lines/'
1 144 270 lines
$ TIMEFORMAT=%R

$ time sed -e '/^-/!d' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' 1.txt > 2.txt
0.357
$ time sed -e '/^-/d' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' 1.txt > 3.txt
0.323

$ time sed -n '/^-/p' 1.txt > 2.txt
0.221
$ time sed -n -r '/^(-|[[:space:]]*$)/!p' 1.txt > 3.txt
0.402
```